# Top align text next to image icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How do i get this piece of HTML working so the text vertically aligns to the top of the image icon and continues to wrap below?

Here's what i have so far:

```
<div style="width:300px;">
        <i class="icon-twitter icon-4x"></i> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit adipiscing elit adipiscing elit adipis Lorem ipsum dolor dolor</span>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xe9zD/

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the default bootstrap css, it includes helper classes to float left and right.  if you add the class pull-left to your icon, it will float it left.

`<i  class="icon-twitter icon-4x pull-left"></i>`

EDIT: And that also gives it a nice margin so it does not butt up against the text.  Its part of your font awesome css file.

Comment: Gonna give this to you purely based on the pull-left class.  No extra css required.

Answer (score 3):

Add this CSS rule:

```
.icon-twitter.icon-4x {
    float:left;
}
```

**[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xe9zD/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

[**Working DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xe9zD/4/)
use float left

```
.icon-twitter icon-4x
{
   float: left;
}
```

if it is directly coming from live css then

```
<i style="float:left;" class="icon-twitter icon-4x"></i> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit adipiscing elit adipiscing elit adipis Lorem ipsum dolor dolor</span>
```

Comment: i knew it was something simple!

Comment: you just had to provide float:left

Comment: yeah but i just added content from live link :) which is extra i know